When talking about the date of an event, what does 'net' mean in an expression like 'net September'
a wiki article gives a date in the form of 'NET September', what does 'net' mean?


The dotted underline indicates you can hover over the text for more information. In this case it tells you "NET" means "no earlier than."


Thanks for this.  I've learned a new trick.
